# Custom Listview with editable item

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I would like this type of interface in my android application:

[image]

This interface can be displayed several times in the same activity.

I'm confused on how I should proceed. Do I have a listview with different custom item?

Is it even possible to do this with xml layout ?

I know how to use custom items in Listview, but i don't know how to do this item. Or have to use a gridview?

Comment: You can use recyclerview and cardview : https://github.com/ahmadaghazadeh/recyclerviewcardview

Comment: thanks for your repsonse, so i will use recyclerview and cardview.
Now I have to create the file that allows me to get this representation of item, and it is mainly my question. I do not know how to do it. Do you have a track on which I can throw myself? Thank you

Comment: what number of row, column? and are the color blue, yellow and gray is EditText?

Comment: 9 column and 4 row, exactly as shown in the picture. yes yellow and blue is edittext.
Thanks man to help me !:)